# jtable.org in row editing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-jtable

I am using http://www.jtable.org/
I want to inline row editing rather than separate form.
I can't any help online.
Is there any way to implement in line row editing using jtable

Comment: I finally moved to JQGrid that is cool

Answer (score 0):

jTable is a CRUD front end to a database. It is not a grid tool.

Heaps of code can make it inline, but you will overwriting much of jTable. Probably easier to find a different tool.